# Grep: First word in line that begins with ? and ends with?

Tags: grep

I'm trying to do a grep command that finds all lines in a file whos first word begins "as" and whos first word also ends with "ng"

How would I go about doing this using grep?

Answer (score 17):

This should just about do it:

```
$ grep '^as\w*ng\b' file
```

**Regexplanation:**

```
^    # Matches start of the line
as   # Matches literal string as
\w   # Matches characters in word class
*    # Quantifies \w to match either zero or more
ng   # Matches literal string ng
\b   # Matches word boundary
```

May have missed the odd corner case.

If you only want to print the words that match and not the whole lines then use the `-o` option:

```
$ grep -o '^as\w*ng\b' file
```

Read `man grep` for all information on the available options.

Comment: Looks like the same format as I suggested, but the explanation is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this should work:

```
grep "^as[a-zA-Z]*ng\b" <filename>
```

hard to say without seeing samples from the actual input file.

Comment: The `.*` will be too greedy and over match i.e `as as ng`.

Comment: This command appears to look at the entire line, rather than the first word, after running it. Hmm.

Comment: @sudo_O Very true, messed up on that one.

Answer (score 1):

sudo has already covered it well, but I wanted to throw out one more simple one:

```
grep -i '^as[^ ]*ng\b' <file>

-i     to make grep case-insensitive
[^ ]*  matches zero or more of any character, except a space
```

Answer (score 0):

`^` finds the 'first character in a line', so you can search for that with:

```
grep '^as' [file]
```

`\w` matches a word character, so `\w*` would match any number of word characters:

```
grep '^as\w*' [file]
```

`\b` means 'a boundary between a word and whitespace' which you can use to ensure that you're matching the 'ng' letters at the end of the word, instead of just somewhere in the middle:

```
grep '^as\w*ng\b' [file]
```

If you choose to omit the `[file]`, simply pipe your files into it:

```
cat [file] | grep '^as\w*ng\b'
```

or

```
echo [some text here] | grep '^as\w*ng\b'
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124927/grep-first-word-in-line-that-begins-with-and-ends-with#comment31788306_21125002